# Android Emulator Visual Studio 2017: Where is My Application?

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, android-emulator, visual-studio-2017

I have a problem with visual studio 2017 android emulator.

I created a project with type "Cross Platform App (Xamarin.Forms or Native". So now I just have the template application, I have not changed anything. Then I press run debug. The android emulator runs fine, but it shows locked screen at first. If I unlock the locked screen, I ended up with the home screen.

Then where is my application? Is not it suppose to debug the application? Why does  it only emulate the android? Where can I find my application?

Comment: unlock the screen before you deploy the app?  also leave the emulator up between runs.  are you using google emulators or the vs-emulators?

Comment: It does take a while for the first deploy to complete.  Are you sure the visual studio was done deploying?

Comment: I see, the loading is taking a lot of time. It is about 3 - 4 minutes. Is there a way to make it fast?

Comment: similar issue.  With a fresh install of VS 2017 and the Xamarin components and the latest SDKs downloaded through the VS SDK for Android interface, some emulators manage to boot to the OS and some get to  a strange shapes overlaying shapes with text that runs off screen....however, using only the Android template project and F5, nothing ever happens (even with clicking buttons and attempts to swipe and unlock the screen.)  Back in the day, WP7 dev was easy, why is this broken for so many of us?